# load bipartite graph into igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following weighted edge list for a bipartite (two mode) graph  where `A` and `B` are two node types and `W` is the weight of the edge... (there are only 6 nodes in `g`)

```
g <- read.table(text="

 A  B   W

 1  55  3
 2  55  5
 3  99  6 ",header=TRUE)
```

I want to draw this graph in `igraph`.  However loading the graph in from this format is not simple.  I was working with  `tnet` which has a nice export to `igraph` function which I usually use:

```
tnet_igraph(sample, type="weighted one-mode tnet")
```

This fails when we have a weighted bipartite graph like `g` above. Is there a straightforward way to get data from the format of `g` into `igraph`?

Other options are very welcome if people prefer something different to `igraph` for drawing bipartite graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called `graph.data.frame` in `igraph` which seems to load the table just fine for me:

```
> g
  A  B W
1 1 55 3
2 2 55 5
3 3 99 6
> g <- graph.data.frame(g)
> vcount(g)
[1] 5
> ecount(g)
[1] 3
> E(g)$W
[1] 3 5 6
```